# Website Blank After Installing Google AppEngine Plugin For Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I spent the better part of yesterday getting my first wordpress website setup on Google AppEngine.  The website was successfully deployed and live to the web through my a custom domain.  All was working fine except I wasn't able to search or upload a plugin.  I have the billing enabled and the cloud storage and cloud sql setup as well.

I did an update from my local environment with the appengine, memcache, and batcache plugins.  I was able to see them all in the plugins folder in the live site.  I then tried to enable the appengine plugin and my site went blank.

I see the url in the top bar but the page itself is completely blank.

Comment: There seems to be a conflict with the Google Cloud Storage plugin and Contact Form 7, best bet is to post to the Wordpress forum for the plugin.

Comment: I wonder if I have cloudstorage setup correctly?  Should I be seeing files in there?  My cloud storage appears to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you dont have specified storage bucket in App Engine plugin here:  gs:///wpcf7_uploads/. Normally after gs:// your storage bucket would appear with proper setup.

You have to make sure also that you add permissions to access the bucket for your application. 
You can get Service Account Name from App Engine -> Administration -> Application Settings and make sure its added to Cloud Storage -> Bucket Permissions when you select your bucket.

Answer (score 0):

In your wp-config.php set wp_cache to false.